# If 15% of the uk population follow cricket, what is the probability that at least 10 out of 50 people follow cricket?

Tags: probability, statistics

Not sure how to go about this question. I understand that the 15% is the population of UK. The 50 people is just a sample, so I'm not sure how the 15% can be used to calculate the probability of there being at least 10 out of the 50 people that follow cricket.

Comment: Let $X$ denot the random variable of the number of people follow the cricket. Then X is binomial distributed with p=0.15, n=50. You have to calculate $P(X\geq 10)=1-P(X\leq 9)=1-P(X=9)-P(X=8)-...-P(X=0)$.  You can apply the binomial distribution or you can approximate X by the normal distribution.

Comment: Of course, this is a binomial distribution! Thank you so much.

Comment: You´re welcome.

Comment: In R: `1-pbinom(9, 50, .15)` returns 0.2089063. Normal approximation with continuity correction gives 2-place accuracy: `1-pnorm(9.5, 7.5, 2.525)` returns 0.2141572 (or standardize and use printed normal tables).